# Generate CSV file on button click in jinja2 template using python

Tags: python, html, pandas, jinja2

I have a jinja2 template which will generate a html in local. HTML contains many tables. I wanted to convert those tables into a csv file when we click on the submit button "convert to csv" in html. I am getting error while trying the below code.

## jinja2 template  -  high_conf_correct_tab1 and low_conf_incorrect_tab1 coming from the python code which contains table data.

```
<form method='post'>
    <button type="submit" >Convert to CSV </button>
</form>

<br>
    <button id=high-conf-correct1 type="button" class="collapsible">Top 1 High Confidence Correct answer </button>
    <div class="content">
        {{high_conf_correct_tab1}}
    </div>
    <div>
        </br>  </br>
    </div>
    <button id=low-conf-incorrect1  type="button" class="collapsible">Top 1 Low Confidence Incorrect answer </button>
    <div class="content">
        {{low_conf_incorrect_tab1}}
    </div>
```

Tried python code:

```
  url = "C:\\Users\\Docs\\html\\metrics.html"
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
       html = open(url).read()
       soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
       table = soup.select_one("table.data2_s")
       with open("out.csv", "w") as f:
                wr = csv.writer(f)
                wr.writerow(headers)
    f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following configuration of form in html for this,

```
<form class="form-container" method="POST" action='/something.html'>
       <input type="submit" id="submit1" class='btn btn-success'>
</form>
```

'something.html' is the url for django backend.

Comment: This is for jinja2. We are not moving to anyother html but the ultimate aim is convert all the table to csv format.